# How to know the user the UWP application runs with

Tags: powershell, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

How can I **non programmatically** to know, what the user, the UWP application runs with.
The application runs on Windows IoT 10 Core.
Is there some commands sequence for Power Shell for know the user?

Comment: Have you tried using the get-process commandlet? Here's the MS documentation for it: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6)
I would suggest you use the command to resolve the process name and then have a look at : Get-Process <insert_process_name> -IncludeUserName

Comment: Yes, it works. The magic is that tab-tab completes the process name here, and also it is possible to see in process list in devices portal. Can you write it in answer, and I will mark it as right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the get-process commandlet?

Here's the MS documentation for it: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6)

I would suggest you use the command to resolve the process name and then have a look at :

```
Get-Process <insert_process_name> -IncludeUserName
```

Hope it helps ;)